# Suckerfish dropdown omitted in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, suckerfish

Using suckerfish dropdown here: http://tilwellpetroleum.com/

Client is not seeing the dropdowns (hover over "About Us") in IE7 Vista. I am not able to reproduce the issue on my end.

I know CSS pretty well but I am stumped. any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling it's the span tag wrapping the About Us.  Try removing the span tag so that "About Us" is wrapped only with the anchor tag and see if that works
OR
try adding display:inline-block to the span tag.  According to http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/82556 he had a similar issue and that resolved it.

Wish I could be more helpful, but I don't have IE7.  Hope this helps.